# Could not find an open port at x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-install, npx

So, I recently started learning React but am running into a few problems if someone would be kind enough to help me out with.
I am creating an application using the code.

```
npx create-react-app project-name
```

The application gets created, but when I try to run it using

```
npm start
```

I get the following error:
**Could not find an open port at x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu.**

Can someone kindly guide me on how to overcome this? Thank you

The message log is as follows:

**Attempting to bind to HOST environment variable: x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu
If this was unintentional, check that you haven't mistakenly set it in your shell.
Learn more here: https://cra.link/advanced-config**

Comment: Can you paste the logs here?

Comment: just did, Kindly check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the problem:

1. I wrote HOST="localhost" to ~.bash_profile via my command line
   editor of choice nano
2. I “reloaded” the environment variables with source ~/.bash_profile

For more details, check this [link](https://choy.medium.com/fixing-create-react-app-when-npm-fails-to-start-because-your-host-environment-variable-is-being-4c8a9fa0b461).

Adding specific steps for Ubuntu:

1. Change the hostname using hostnamectl.

   In Ubuntu 18.04 we can change the system hostname and related settings
   using the command hostnamectl.

For example, to change the system static hostname to linuxize, you would
use the following command:

```
  sudo hostnamectl set-hostname localhost
```

Copy
The hostnamectl command does not produce output. On success, 0 is returned, a non-zero failure code otherwise.

2. Edit the /etc/hosts file.
   Open the /etc/hosts file and change the old hostname to the new one.

```
/etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost


# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Copy
3. Edit the cloud.cfg file.

If the cloud-init package is installed you also need to edit the cloud.cfg file. This package is usually installed by default in the images provided by the cloud providers such as AWS and it is used to handle the initialization of the cloud instances.

To check if the package is installed run the following `ls command`:

```
ls -l /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg
```

Comment: I just checked my HOST, but can you kindly tell me how to edit the HOST to LOCALHOST in bash_profile as suggested in the link?

Comment: what is the o/p for this `echo $HOST` or `hostnamectl` in your terminal? Please share that. Also, what is the shell you are using?

Comment: I solved it from the link you sent, Apparently I just had to type HOST=localhost npm start.

Answer (score 4):

Found the solution. Just typed

```
HOST=localhost npm start
```

working smoothly now

Comment: Remember, you need to always set host this way. This is a temporary way to set the host.

Comment: I dont know how to edit it in the environment variable on Ubuntu. Looking into it

Comment: Just updated the permanent way for doing it.