# Can't change HOST env variable in conda env

Tags: environment-variables, conda, zsh, hostname

I can change **HOST** env variable in conda ***base*** env *(as shown below)*

However, I can't change it in other conda env, in my case, it is ***foo*** env

```sh
~ ❯ echo $HOST                                           base
localhost
~ ❯ HOST=bar                                             base
~ ❯ echo $HOST                                           base
bar
~ ❯ conda activate foo                                   base
~ ❯ echo $HOST                                           foo
x86_64-conda-linux-gnu
~ ❯ HOST=bar                                             foo
~ ❯ echo $HOST                                           foo
x86_64-conda-linux-gnu
```

I also tried `export` but no luck:

```sh
~ ❯ export HOST=bar                                      foo
~ ❯ echo $HOST                                           foo
x86_64-conda-linux-gnu
```

I want to change the **HOST** variable in order to follow [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67057497/11806050).

I'm using *zsh*, however when I changed to *bash*, everything works **fine**.

So how can I change the **HOST** variable (in conda env ***foo*** in *zsh*)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Workaround

A workaround is to chain the command:

```bash
~ ❯ HOST=localhost && echo $HOST
localhost
```

This doesn't solve the issue that you can't persist the value, but at least you can launch stuff with it defined as you wish.

### Source of Issue

I'm not familiar with details of `zsh`, but this specific behavior by the Conda environment seems caused by the `gcc_linux-64` package, which includes [these lines in its activation script](https://github.com/conda-forge/ctng-compiler-activation-feedstock/blob/77a5dca5587a8e8360609e9f7e29bb65606689d9/recipe/activate-gcc.sh#L192):

```bash
# fix prompt for zsh
if [[ -n "${ZSH_NAME:-}" ]]; then
    autoload -Uz add-zsh-hook

    _conda_clang_precmd() {
      HOST="${CONDA_BACKUP_HOST}"
    }
    add-zsh-hook -Uz precmd _conda_clang_precmd

    _conda_clang_preexec() {
      HOST="${CONDA_TOOLCHAIN_HOST}"
    }
    add-zsh-hook -Uz preexec _conda_clang_preexec
fi
```

Roughly, seems like this compiler toolchain requires HOST to be set in a particular way, and for some reason `zsh` makes it problematic to change it. The code here appears to use hooks to set HOST right *before* executing a command, and then restores it from the backup right before showing the prompt again.

I encourage you to file [an issue on the pertinent feedstock](https://github.com/conda-forge/ctng-compiler-activation-feedstock/issues), asking why they are doing this and if it could be changed.